# Reading array of objects of a class from a file

Tags: java, filereader

I have a class of three fields, two `int` and a `double`. I have made a list of my class objects and would like to read the object of the array, line by line, from a text file using `Scanner`, `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`.

MWE:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Model {
    public static final int Y = 7;
    public static final int K = 42;
    public static final int G = 3;

public static class Sleg {
        // private int id;
        private int i;
        private int j;
        private double l;

        public Sleg(int i, int j, double l) {
            // this.id = id;
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
            this.l = l;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(j) + " " + Double.toString(l);
        }
    }


    public static void dataGen() {

        System.out.print("slegs = ");


          /*List<Sleg> slegs = Arrays.asList(); I want to write it like this and 
          read it from slFile.txt instead of the following line where the slegs are put one by one.*/
        List<Sleg> slegs = Arrays.asList(new Sleg(1,2,400),new Sleg(2,5,800),new Sleg(5,7,450),new Sleg(2,3,800),new Sleg(3,6,500),new Sleg(3,4,500),new Sleg(4,5,500),new Sleg(7,5,450),new Sleg(5,4,500),new Sleg(4,3,400),new Sleg(6,3,550),new Sleg(3,2,700),new Sleg(2,1,400), new Sleg(5,2,800));

        System.out.print(slegs);
        System.out.println("]");

        System.out.print("slegs = [");
        for (Sleg s : slegs) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.println("]");

        System.out.print("slegs = [");
        Sleg list2[] = new Sleg[slegs.size()];
        list2 = slegs.toArray(list2);

        File slFile = new File("slFile.txt");
        try {
            Scanner in7 = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("slFile.txt")));

            while(in7.hasNextLine()) {
                for (int sl = 0; sl < list2.length; sl++) {
                    String[] line = in7.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
                    list2[sl] = Double.parseDouble(line);                
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read : " + slFile.toString());
        }

        for (Sleg i : list2) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println("]");

        System.out.print("slegs = [");
        Object[] ss = slegs.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ss[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("]");


          int[][] u = new int [slegs.size()][G];
    }
}
```

data in slFile.tex:

```
1 2 400
2 5 800
5 7 450
2 3 800
3 6 550
3 4 500
4 5 500
7 5 450
5 4 500
4 3 400
6 3 550
3 2 700
2 1 400
5 2 800
```

However, an error is popping up " change the line to String". If I have an array of 3 dimension instead of my slegs objects of class Sleg containing 3 fields, I knew how to read the file, but for this, I don're have any idea. 
I'd appreciate your ideas!

Comment: Please post the data in the `slFile.txt` file.

Comment: I have edited the post and put it there.

Comment: Can you use `ArrayLists` instead of `arrays`?

Comment: if I can then define int u[slegs][g], yes.

Comment: I think you should also post class `Sleg` so we can tell how to construct it properly

Comment: My bad! I have incororated Sleg class into the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems with the code that you've provided. You're trying to use `Boolean.parseBoolean(String)` with a `String[]`, you're assuming the number of lines in the text file, the `list2` variable is of type `Sleg[]` but you're attempting to assign a `double` to it's elements, and various other things.

Assuming that you're just interested in reading the file into a list of `Slug` objects you probably want to do something like this:

```
// Use a list since the length of the file is unkown
List<Sleg> slegs = new ArrayList<Sleg>();

File slFile = new File("slFile.txt");

// Use try-with-resources block so the reader is closed automatically,
// no need to use Scanner since we're only interested in reading lines...
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("slFile.txt"))) {

    // Read the file line by line
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Split the line, convert values, and add new sleg.
        String[] numbers = line.trim().split(" ");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
        int j = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
        double l = Double.parseDouble(numbers[2]);
        slegs.add(new Sleg(i, j , l));
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(slFile.toString() + " does not exist.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle any possible IOExceptions as well...
    System.out.println("Unable to read : " + slFile.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I used LinkedList because I didn't know how many items/lines were there (I could have count them, but if there is no indication as to how many lines are there, i.e first line indicating the number of items... I will use a Linkedlist). Now, your method `dataGen` will return a `LinkedList` storing `Sleg` Objects. Here is a working MVCE:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Model {

    public static final int Y = 7;
    public static final int K = 42;
    public static final int G = 3;

    public Model() {

        dataGen();
    }

    public LinkedList<Sleg> dataGen() {
        LinkedList<Sleg> data = new LinkedList<>();
        File slFile = new File("slFile.txt");
        try {
            Scanner in7 = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("slFile.txt")));
            while (in7.hasNextLine()) {
                //get current line and split it via a space.
                String[] split = in7.nextLine().split(" ");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                double z = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
                Sleg newItem = new Sleg(x, y, z);//new entry.
                data.add(newItem);//add as an entry to data.
            }
            in7.close();//should have this!!!
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read : " + slFile.toString());
        }
        for (Sleg current : data) {
            System.out.println(current.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Model();
    }

    class Sleg {

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        double z = 0;

        Sleg(int x, int y, double z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
while(in7.hasNextLine()) {
    for (int sl = 0; sl < list2.length; sl++) {
        String[] line = in7.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
        list2[sl] = Double.parseDouble(line);                
    }
}
```

1. You can not parse an array of strings to a double: `Double.parseDouble(line)`.
2. You can not assign a double to a object reference either (i.e.: `Sleg` here): `list2[sl] = Double.parseDouble(line)`.
3. The operation of reading next line should be placed in outer while loop: `String[] line = in7.nextLine().trim().split(" ");`.
4. `for` loop is unnecessary as you only process one element per loop cycle (not all elements in `list2`).

Base on the above, those can be modified to:

```
int sl = 0;
while(in7.hasNextLine() && sl < list2.length) {
    String[] line = in7.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    if (line.length < 3) {
        System.out.println("invalid line: " + line);
        continue;
    }
    list2[sl] = new Sleg(
        Integer.parseInt(line[0]),
        Integer.parseInt(line[1]),
        Double.parseInt(line[2])
    );
    sl++;
}
```